# Create redirect after registration Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want after successful registration I was redirected to `successfull.blade.php` , but for some reason it either gives a 404 error, that the page was not found, or that it always throws me to home ... I can’t handle it please help me.
After successful registration, I should be thrown to `successfull.blade.php`
Please help me.

> RegistersUsers.php

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
      $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

      event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

      $this->guard()->login($user);

      return $this->registered($request, $user)
      ?: redirect()->to('/successfull');
}
```

> RegisterController

```
protected function redirectPath()
{
  if (Auth::user()->role_id==NULL) {
    return '/successfull';
  } else {
    return '/successfull';
  }
}
```

> web.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@getUser')->name('users');

Route::get('/successfull', 'Auth\RegisterController@redirectPath');
```

> homecontroller

```
public function getUser(){

        $user=auth()->user();
         return view('home',[
                'users' =>  $user,
            ]);
}
```

throws me to `home` because of `homecontroller`, but I want it to be only after login, and after registration I need to be redirected to another file

Comment: so is it always redirecting to home after registration

Comment: I need to redirect to `successfull` after registration, and after a simple login to `home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Routes:**
    `define` a new `function` in `HomeController` named as `success` and call `success.blade.php` inside function.

```
Route::get('/successfull', 'HomeController@success');
```

**RegisterController**

```
if (Auth::user()->role_id != NULL) {
  return redirect('/successfull');
}
```

**RegistersUsers.php**

after user account created successfully

```
redirect('/successfull')->withSuccess(' Account Created Successfully');
```

Hope it will help you :)