# Laravel redirect Auth::guart('admin') logout to admin login screen

Tags: php, laravel

I have additional Auth::guard('admin') and want to redirect to `admin/login` screen on `logout` but somehow it is always going to site `/` home.

## LoginController

```
public function adminLogout()
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
}
```

## View - app.blade.php

```
@if(Auth::guard('web')->check())

    <a class="dropdown-item"
       href="{{ route('logout') }}"
       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        {{ __('Logout') }}
    </a>

@elseif(Auth::guard('admin')->check())

    <a class="dropdown-item"
       href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}"
       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        {{ __('Logout') }}
    </a>

@endif
```

## Route

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

    ...
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@adminLogout')->name('admin.logout');
    ...

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create redirect after registration Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145365/create-redirect-after-registration-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your 'logout-form'.

In your HTML you have used logout-form, to be submitted on click of logout button, you need to change action URL of that form, to perform your custom logout action.
Currently it is going on the same route to logout.

Most probably your logout form would be something like this,

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
  @csrf
</form>
```

Change `{{ route('logout')}}` as per your conditions.

Comment: I see, let me try to do that. Thanks